# Laravel too many open files error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, nginx, server

I had run the Laravel with Nginx server for very long time. But today, I just got

> Too many open files

error. And I just rebooted my Ubuntu server and it work fine. Why that was ok? What configuration did I need to do for that not to fix that kind of error in the future?

Comment: what is the output of `ulimit -a`?

Comment: @xkcd149 Please see the result on http://pastebin.com/raw/w3y2xjDP